# Planning a user interface for product search

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am planning to create a WP7 application for searching in a catalog. I will have a search form and a results page.
I think I will need a plain page for searching and a panorama page for results, with item list  on the left and details of the selected item on the right (and maybe further details in a third page)
Am I on the right track? Is this the natural way to o that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need one page with a search TextBox at top and displaying results below (search-as-you-type). Then you can click on an item and a details page will open (without panorama). Example: Go to people hub click on the search button...

search-as-you-type: Call your web service to get the result list. Do this every time the text has changed and the last request was more then 1 second ago... (to prevent too much requests)